# Where can I "update" the quality profiles of PHP in sonarqube?

Tags: java, php, continuous-integration, sonarqube

In sonarqube the quality profiles available in PHP are only the followings:

- Drupal
- PSR-2
- Sonar Way

As explained here [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) and here [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/), PSR-2 is deprecated.
So why sonarqube still use this profile instead of the new one?
Is there a way to download and import the new PSR-12 ?
I tried googling about quality profiles, but I found only documentation on building new profiles from scratch.

(My projects are mostly built on Laravel, so if there are some quality profiles specific to this framework, could add more control on top of PSR-12)

Comment: Same for Java. Java 16 and Java 17 is not supported by the latest LTS release and I would love to import the "Sonar way" Java quality profile!